# How many enhancements it is possible to balance?

Tags: darksiders-3

So, in Darksiders III, balancing single enhancement requires 12 demonic and 12 angelic artifacts, and one Essence of the Chosen. Obviously, resources are limited, as you find artifacts in the world, or buy limited amount from Vulgrim, and Chosen are supposed to be hidden bosses (I've encountered only one so far).

So, my question is - how many enhancements I can balance?

Answer (score 1):

I just finished my first playthrough and I managed to fully balance 5 enhancements. Yet I still got a spare Essence of the Chosen.

I do believe that I missed some artifacts but that would total to 12 angel and 10 demoic artifacts that I would have missed.

So theoretically it should be possible to balance 6 enhancements in one playthrough whereas 5 are pretty safe.

EDIT:

I just found another one. So far I could balance a total of 7 if I had the artifacts

EDIT 2:

With the release of "The Crucible" DLC, all enhancements can be balanced with enough farming, as the required materials can be bought at Targon.

EDIT 3:

With the release of Armageddon Mode AKA new game plus, it is possible to simply replay the game multiple to balance all enhancements.